# Can not initialize array correctly

Tags: ruby

I've been trying to code some algorithm in a minified manner>.
I believe that typical 2d array defining is looks too unwieldy

```
 mx = Array.new(N) { Array.new(N) }
```

I am trying to use another hint, but it's behaviour is a bit strange for me:

```
 mx = [[!:&]*n]*n
```

Take a look:

```
#square matrix n*n
n=3
mx = [[!:&]*n]*n
#=> [[false, false, false], [false, false, false], [false, false, false]]

mx[0][0]=true       

mx
#=> [[true, false, false], [true, false, false], [true, false, false]]
#     true                  true                  true ????
#.
```

How should I tame my array? 
[repl.it_snippet: avaiable](https://repl.it/BPRO/3)

Comment: To start with, why use `!:&` instead of `false`? It's trying to be confusing on purpose?

Comment: ..you Got tha't smile above, yea?)

Answer (score 3):

This is because the sub arrays are the same instance

```
#square matrix n*n 
n=3
mx = [[!:&]*n]*n
#=> [[false, false, false], [false, false, false], [false, false, false]]

mx[0] === mx[1]
# true

mx[1] === mx[2]
# true
```

to fix the code, add something like that

```
n=3
mx = [[!:&]*n]*n
mx = mx.flatten.each_slice(n).to_a
mx[0][0] = true
mx
# [[true, false, false], [false, false, false], [false, false, false]]
```

or

```
n=3
mx = ([!:&]*n*n).each_slice(n).to_a
mx[0][0] = true
mx
# [[true, false, false], [false, false, false], [false, false, false]]
```